# If range is blank, put an "X" in column B - excel

Tags: excel

Ive got a spreadsheet with a matrix chart with "x" in columns `d:s` in column `b` i want to write a formula `if`d:s`ISBLANK write "blank" in column B`.

To do this i tried : `=IF(ISBLANK(C2:S2) , "blank", "not blank")`

But it always equates to "not blank". Any ideas where ive gone wrong ?

Ive created a sample spreadsheet for testing here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-LyPDld5a3WZue7zYSGvFbYy-tDZQLAcsRpNq4yBnU/edit#gid=0

Comment: So you want it to be `"blank"` if every cell in `C2:S2` is blank, and `"not blank"` if there are any non-blank cells? You could do this with `COUNTA()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with COUNTA(range):

- if COUNTA(range) returns something different than 0, then the range is not blank
- else, the range is blank

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to evaluate all of the cells in C2:S2 (an array) so the formula needs to be evaluated as an array formula.

Assuming that you want to display "Not Blank" if any of the cells have contents include an AND with your ISBLANK, then evaluate as an array formula.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(C2:S2)),"Blank","Not Blank")
```

Try the expression with ctrl + shift + enter.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most semantic way to write the formula, rather than using a count function as some other answers, but when tested in the google drive spreadsheet it was giving the answer of "not blank" for everything

Comment: @sam This is very curious indeed. I just tested in Excel and on GoogleDocs. You are very sure that it is evaluating as an array formula?

Answer (score 1):

try this
=IF(COUNTBLANK(D2:S2)=16,"blank","")